# Logout on pressing back button in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I've noticed on internet banking sites that you get automatically logged out and sent to a warning page if you hit the back button on your browser, ending your session and obliging you to log in again. I want to implement the same feature in codeigniter. Kindly suggest me how to achieve this in codeigniter.

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
     if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
         window.history.pushState('', null, './');
         $(window).on('popstate', function() {
             // alert('Back button was pressed.');
             // document.location.href = '#';
             document.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>master-panel/logout.html';

         });
     }
  });
 </script>
```

I have used the above code and it seems to work absolutely fine. But is there any other way other than using jquery to achieve this result? As because the above code can easily be altered by inspect element from developer tools. Can we do this in php.

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: Use javascript to detect if user has pressed the back button. Using this approach first try something of your own then edit your question with your code so that we can help you out.

Comment: In config file you can set session expire time like `$config['sess_expiration'] = 'your desired time'.` and make sure your login session should be unset.. for more details about session expire https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-31039.html

Comment: <script>
  $(function() {
     if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
         window.history.pushState('', null, './');
         $(window).on('popstate', function() {
             // alert('Back button was pressed.');
             // document.location.href = '#';
             document.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>master-panel/logout.html';

         });
     }
  });
 </script>

Comment: I have used the above code and it seems to work absolutely fine. But is there any other way other than using jquery to achieve this result? As because the above code can easily be altered by inspect element from developer tools. Can we do this in php.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, as you can see it's hard to read. Instead, please edit your question and paste the code there, so it's all in one place. Thanks